# How to open an existing record in a form with a click of menu item in openerp?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I have created a menu item- 'Personal Profile'.
On click, it should open the candidate profile in a form view.
I have set rules so that each candidate can see only his/her profile.
In action part of the menu I have - defined view_type as form & view_mode as form,kanban
But,by default on click of the menu item a new form is opened for create.
Instead I want my existing record form view(i.e user/candidate profile) should be displayed every time when I click the menu item.

Please Help..

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the user data in preferences (user defaults) or plist file,database any of these  data source.
Than on click you need to check if  data exist in these data source than fetch and fill out data in form or  if no data exist than open blank form.

Comment: can u explain how can we make a plist file in openerp?